# Neural network XOR learning

Tags: neural-network, ada, xor

Im struggling to test if my neural network is working properly and I have tried with XOR because that is the simple test case.

Is the XOR a good test case or should I use something else?

I have set up my neural network code in Ada and I have modeled after [this tutorial](http://home.agh.edu.pl/~vlsi/AI/backp_t_en/backprop.html). My neural network with (2-inputs, 3-hidden, 1-output) can not learn XOR. What is the problem in following code?

```
with Ada.Text_IO;use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions;


procedure Main is

   Learning_Rate : Float := 0.5;

   function Sigmoid(X : Float) return Float is
      package Math is new Ada.Numerics.Generic_Elementary_Functions(Float); use Math;
      e : constant Float := 2.7;
   begin
      return 1.0 / (1.0 + e**(-X));
   end;

   function Sigmoid_Derivative (X : Float) return Float is
   begin
      return Sigmoid(X) * (1.0 - Sigmoid(X));
   end;


   type Float_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Float;
   type Node;
   type Node is record
      S : Float := 0.0; --Summation
      Y : Float := 0.0; --Output
      W : Float_Array(1..10) := (others => 0.0); --Weigths
      D : Float := 0.0; --Delta error
   end record;
   type Layer is array (Positive range <>) of Node;



   --Forward calculations

   procedure Calculate_Summation (N : in out Node; L : in Layer) is
   begin
      N.S := 0.0;
      for Index in L'Range loop
         N.S := N.S + L(Index).Y * N.W(Index);
      end loop;
   end;

   procedure Calculate_Summation (Destination : in out Layer; Source : in Layer) is
   begin
      for N of Destination loop
         Calculate_Summation(N, Source);
      end loop;
   end;

   procedure Calculate_Output (L : in out Layer) is
   begin
      for N of L loop
         N.Y := Sigmoid(N.S);
      end loop;
   end;


   --Backpropogation

   procedure Calculate_Delta (L : in out Layer; N : in Node ) is
   begin
      for Index in L'Range loop
         L(Index).D := L(Index).D + N.D * N.W(Index);
      end loop;
   end;

   procedure Calculate_Delta (Destination : in out Layer; Source : in Layer) is
   begin
      for N of Source loop
         Calculate_Delta(Destination, N);
      end loop;
   end Calculate_Delta;


   function Calculate_Delta_Weight(D, S, X : Float) return Float is
   begin
      return Learning_Rate * D * Sigmoid_Derivative(S) * X;
   end;


   --Weight adjustment

   procedure Calculate_Weight(N : in out Node; L : in Layer) is
   begin
      for Index in L'Range loop
         N.W(Index) := N.W(Index) + Calculate_Delta_Weight(N.D, N.S, L(Index).Y);
      end loop;
      N.D := 0.0;
   end;

   procedure Calculate_Weight(Destination : in out Layer; Source : in Layer) is
   begin
      for N of Destination loop
         Calculate_Weight(N, Source);
      end loop;
   end;

   LI : Layer(1..2);
   LH : Layer(1..3);
   LO : Layer(1..1);

   procedure Learn (A, B, Target : Float) is
   begin

      LI(1).Y := A;
      LI(2).Y := B;

      Calculate_Summation( Source => LI, Destination => LH );
      Calculate_Output(LH);

      Calculate_Summation( Source => LH, Destination => LO );
      Calculate_Output(LO);

      LO(1).D := Target - LO(1).Y;

      Put("A,B,T ="); Put(A, 3,3,0);Put(B, 3,3,0);Put(Target, 3,3,0);
      Put("     Y ="); Put(LO(1).Y, 3,3,0);
      Put("     D ="); Put(LO(1).D, 3,3,0);

      Calculate_Delta(Source => LO, Destination => LH);

      Calculate_Weight(Source => LH, Destination => LO);
      Calculate_Weight(Source => LI, Destination => LH);

   end;


begin

   for I in 1..1000 loop
      Learn(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);New_Line;
      Learn(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);New_Line;
      Learn(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);New_Line;
      Learn(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);New_Line;
      New_Line;
   end loop;
end Main;
```

The last output is:

```
A,B,T =  1.000  1.000  0.000     Y =  0.497     D = -0.497
A,B,T =  1.000  0.000  1.000     Y =  0.495     D =  0.505
A,B,T =  0.000  1.000  1.000     Y =  0.494     D =  0.506
A,B,T =  0.000  0.000  0.000     Y =  0.505     D = -0.505
```

Where Y is output from the neural network and T is wanted target.

Comment: The topology of your network does not appear to match the tutorial (3 input neurons, 2 hidden, 1 output) Possibly significant?

Comment: @Brian Drummond That tutorial is a example on the logic behind neural network and not related to XOR gate specifically.

Comment: XOR is most definitely a good test as it is not linearly separable, so needs requires a working hidden layer.

Comment: Have you considered looking at how the very _first_ steps of the iteration deviate from the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your weights should be initialized, preferably to random values. For example, `Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Random( foo );`
Second, your network should learn better if you add a bias input (a constant input, for example 1.0)

With this, D should start converging towards 0.0.

You can help yourself in a situation like this by printing all the inputs/outputs and weights in your network, including the hidden layer. In your case, a pattern will emerge that should not be there (a result of all weights being 0.0)

Comment: Some additional information that I have discovered. With the setup (x1,x2,bias=1) -> (h1,h2,h3) -> (y1) and random weights, takes around 1000 iterations of 4 training rows to learn XOR or XNOR gate. The weights may vary between -10.0 to 10.0 when fully learned. And sometimes a output converge to 0.5 instead of 1.0. So the delta error does not always converge to 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Consider splitting a part of your program out in a package.
- Consider declaring your own floating point type with the required precision.
- Consider making `Node` a discriminated type with the number of inputs to the layer as the discriminant.
- Run a simple test-case on paper, and validate that your implementation gets the same result as you get, when you solve the problem by hand.

Neither of these suggestions will necessarily solve your problem, but they will hopefully make it easier for you to *find* the solution.

Answer (score 0):

XOR is a good test case for a neural network, since it cannot be solved by a perceptron. Backpropagation is a simple gradient-descent technique with numerous well known deficiencies. Most modern NN training uses 2nd-derivative information, resulting in more robust and quick training.